# Why is my system trying to update to a package in proposed when proposed is not in my sources.list?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

My sources.list looks like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 
(20180426)]/ bionic main restricted
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 
(20180426)]/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
```

but when I run

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris --no-install-recommends -y install ubuntu-desktop
```

I get packages like **evolution-data-server-common_3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb**, which according to https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-proposed-main-amd64/evolution-data-server-common_3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb.html are part of Ubuntu Proposed Main amd64. Why is this?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/evolution-data-server-common says that's in `-updates`.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for using a third party package listing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third party websites are sometimes a bit behind...or their scraper captures incomplete information.

Sometimes it's better to query the madison database directly. In this case, let's use the `rmadison` script provided by the `devscripts` package.

```
$ rmadison evolution-data-server-common | grep 3.28.5
evolution-data-server-common | 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 | bionic-proposed  | all
evolution-data-server-common | 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 | bionic-updates   | all
```

You can see that the package is in both -updates *and* -proposed. -updates is one of your valid sources.

Let's dig a little deeper on why the package is in both. For this check out the Launchpad source page for the package: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-data-server

A quick look there also validates that the package is in both repositories...and  why: It was added to -updates less than 24 hours ago. It will drop from -proposed soon automatically.